# Different route template than the Controller Name in Web API Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebAPI's in ASP.NET web application, and I am following a YouTube tutorial who doesn't address this confusion, I will say confusion because its not an error per se.

So I am making a simple WEB API using MVC Entity Framework. The Database Model name I have is `DBModel.cs` and another file called `Employeetbl.cs` which is also the same name as the table inside my DB that I have mentioned in the the ADO.NET file, the Controller name is `EmpController.cs`.

Now inside the `EmpController.cs` I have something like this

```
public class EmpController : ApiController
{
    private EmployeeDBEntities db = new EmployeeDBEntities();

    // GET: api/Emp
    public IQueryable<Employeetbl> GetEmployeetbls()
    {
        return db.Employeetbl;
    }
```

the api line is `api/Emp`, shouldnt it be `api/Employeetbl`.
Am I doing something wrong, or do I have to change this manually?
Thanks.

Comment: do you want to change your action route ? or only change your the action name ?

Comment: Yes that, along with the fact as why the Controller name and the route name are different. My controller name is ```EmpController``` but the route ends with ```api/Emp```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little hard to answer your question because you need to read a little more about WEB API and  Web API routing. The `api/Emp` mentions your controller name `EmpController` not your class name `Employeetbl`.It is just a class you return from your `GetEmployeetbls` action. see this code

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

It is routing configuration and some attribute like `[Route("api/..")]` or `[RoutePrefix("api/..")]` can be useful for to make a  better route for the actions.

anyway,[this link can help you to learn about Web API routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

**I hope this link can help you.**

Comment: Without the IDE pre-generated comments, its quite difficult to understand the endpoints, I mean common sense says, the endpoint according to the ```routes.config``` or the other ```webapiroute``` file , route will be ```api/{controller}/{id}``` , now in this case, it means ```localhost:port/api/EmpController  (the controller class name)``` but its something else entirely. But it seems this is an entirely different scenario, so my guessing is totally wrong. Thank you for the link, I will put some time and effort into routing.

Comment: ok, so the endpoint is the name of the controller without suffix "Controller" , So in my case, my controller class name was EmpController, the endpoint ended to be just Emp , because the suffix "Controller" is opted out. So its just ```localhost:port/api/Emp```

Comment: Exactly. The `Emp` is a prefix here and  it is enough to call without using `controller` word, because your controller name is `Emp` and the route configuration is following to a controller name.

Comment: Ya.. That seems to be the thing.